# Triple monitor display that used to work now shows "Could not switch the monitor configuration" error

Tags: 14.04, multiple-monitors

I'm using a Dell Precision Workstation T1700 with 3 Dell monitors. Two plugged into the graphics card via display ports, and the last one rotated 180 degrees and plugged into the integrated VGA port. I'm running Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. My  [display setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iZcxf.png). This setup has worked without issue for about a year, but now I've been having problems.

First, I've been getting a "Could not switch the monitor configuration" error before even logging in. Once I do log in a very similar message would appear and not all of the monitors would display. A work around I found is as follows:
1. Setting all the monitors to 0 degrees rotation and mirroring the display
2. Restart
3. Error still appears, but all the monitors are detected now. Then I can make the changes to extend and rotate monitors
4. Don't restart

I know this setup used to work so I'm hoping there is just a setting I can change somewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally found a solution on http://www.dell.com/support/article/us/en/19/sln298529/how-to-configure-multiple-displays-on-a-dell-pc-using-the-ubuntu-operating-system

1. Run: `sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager`
2. Run: `ccsm`
3. Click 'General Options' in General.
4. Click the Display Settings tab.
5. Uncheck Detect Outputs as seen [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l9K2G.png).